# jquery checkboxes checked only

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of checkboxes tha start with CheckRR_

I like to loop only for ones that starts with "CheckRR_" and are checked. How would I do this?

I have the following so far:

```
$('input[name^="CheckRRR_"]').filter(":visible").each(function () { ....
```

This works for only the ones that are visible, not checked. I like to look for ones that are checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `filter(":checked")` instead. Or just

```
$('input[name^="CheckRRR_"] :checked').each(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name^="CheckRRR_"]:visible:checked')
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this yet?

```
$('input[name^="CheckRRR_"]:checked').each(function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with one selector:

```
$('input[name^="CheckRRR_"]:visible:checked').each(function () {...
```

If you don't care if they are visible or not:

```
$('input[name^="CheckRRR_"]:checked').each(function () {...
```

`:checked` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)